# Can't iterate over datastore object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using the google-app-engine together with python and I can't iterate over a datastore object.

**My DB Model:**

```
class Page(db.Model):
    url = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    author = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    content = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

**This is where the error happens:**

```
def generate_links(self, pages):
    urls = []
    for i, page in pages:
        urls.append(page.url + "?v=" + i)

    return urls
```

I am fetching pages with:

```
pages = Page.all().filter("url = ", link_id).order("-created")
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/google-appengine-python/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
  rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
File "/opt/google-appengine-python/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
  rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "/opt/google-appengine-python/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in   default_dispatcher
  return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "/opt/google-appengine-python/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
  return handler.dispatch()
File "/opt/google-appengine-python/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
  return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "/opt/google-appengine-python/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
  return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/Drive/main.py", line 197, in generate_links
  for i, page in pages:
TypeError: 'Page' object is not iterable
```

However, I can iterate over pages in jinja2 using:

```
{% for page in pages %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not from iterating over `pages`, but from splitting each Page object into two variables, `i` and `page`. In order to make that work, you'd need to wrap it in `enumerate`:

```
 for i, page in enumerate(pages):
```